# Gradle: No matching variant found for BOM included directly and in a dependency

Tags: gradle

I have a BOM that I generate for common third party libraries that I include in all our projects.

dependencies {
implementation enforcedPlatform('ourgroup:third-party-bom:1.0'))
....
}

This works fine for a simple project

When I start to depend on libraries that already depend on the BOM I'm running into the following error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve ourgroup:third-party-bom:1.0.
> Required by:
> project : > ourgroup:somelibrary:4.28.0
> > No matching variant of ourgroup:third-party-bom:1.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 11, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability ourgroup:third-party-bom:1.0 declares an API of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a platform and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
> - Variant 'enforcedApiElements' capability ourgroup:third-party-bom-derived-enforced-platform:1.0 declares an API of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an enforced platform and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)

I can work around this by adding an exclusion of the BOM when I depend on a component that already depends on it

i.e.

```
implementation ('ourgroup:somelibrary')) {
    exclude group: 'ourgroup', module: 'third-party-bom'
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to make this work so I don't have to add exclusions all over the place?